# WCF error - 'Cannot obtain metadata'

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I'm working on my first WCF service and am getting an error when trying to launch the service inside of visual studio. So, it will be running under Cassini.

The error is:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:1393/BEService.svc
```

Here is my configuration

```
         <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="DataServices.BEService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DataServices.IBEService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1393" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Here is my interface that defines the service contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBEService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Get271EDI(string EDI, DDKSLib.Enums.EDIRequestor requestor);
    }
```

Here is the class that implements it :

```
public class BEService : IBEService
    {

        public string Get271EDI(string EDI, Enums.EDIRequestor requestor)
        {
            return "this is a test";
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an interface that defines your Contracts, and a class that implements it? If so, can you please post that code?

Comment: Could the problem be related to running on Cassini?

Comment: It could be related to Cassini, since according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaidu/archive/2006/06/30/652275.aspx), Cassini assigns a new port number on each instance, which will invalidate your endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing the WCF configuration, the editor moved all of the configuration to an app.config file. However, a lot of articles i read referenced configuration being in the web.config instead. So, I moved them to the web.config and deleted the app.config. Everything started working. Then, I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814082/when-does-wcf-use-app-config-or-web-config) question which answered my question about when to use web.config vs app.config..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaking, but I think you need to use a base address for service when endpoint is empty or relative and you don't use IIS, isn't it?

```
<host>
   <baseAddresses>
       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1393/MyService"/>
   </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Here is an article about [WCF Addressing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx)

**EDIT:** You should check more into detail the error that you get. I think there are some inner details which may help you solving the case. It could be that something in your implementation is not conforming to the WCF rules.

Comment: Tried that with same error. Updated question to show change. Will read your link.

Comment: @BillMartin your change doesn't look like what Cristi suggests. You're missing the /MyService/ part. Did you make sure to add that?